# Create nested json object using php mysql - error with nested component

Tags: php, mysql, json, nested

I am trying to create a nested json output from a MySql table, and i am struggling to resolve a problem that arises.

An example of the table is shown below:

| id | county | county_code | region | region_code | entrants | population |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mombasa | KE.28 | Coast | KE.CO | 2526 | 1208333 |
| 2 | Kwale | KE.19 | Coast | KE.CO | 956 | 86682 |
| 18 | Nyandarua | KE.35 | Central | KE.CE | 1153 | 638289 |
| 19 | Nyeri | KE.36 | Central | KE.CE | 824 | 759164 |
| 23 | Turkana | KE-43 | Rift Valley | KE.RV | 183 | 926976 |

I am trying to create the following output:

```json
[
{
    "id": "KE.CE",
    "x": "Central",
    "value": 368505,
    "market_share": 28,
    "total_share": 50,
    "revenue": [
        ["Nyandarua",1153,0.181],
        ["Nyeri",824,0.109],
        ["Kirinyaga",395,0.065],
        ["Murang",487,0.046],
        ["Kiambu",2174,0.09]
    ]
    },
    {
    "id": "KE.CO",
    "x": "Coastal",
    "value": 386097,
    "market_share": 16,
    "total_share": 20,
    "revenue": [
        ["Mombasa",2526,0.209],
        ["Kwale",956,1.103],
        ["Kilifi",1260,0.087],
        ["Tana River",180,0.057],
        ["Lamu",71,0.493],
        ["Taita–Taveta",699,0.205]
    ]
    },
 {
    "id": "KE.RV",
    "x": "Rift Valley",
    "value": 519026,
    "market_share": 29,
    "total_share": 47,
    "revenue": [
        ["West Pokot",242,0.039],
        ["Samburu",64,0.021],
        ["Trans-Nzoia",1566,0.158],
        ["Uasin Gishu",1769,0.152],
        ["Elgeyo-Marakwet",243,0.535],
        ["Nandi",1929,0.218],
        ["Baringo",504,0.076],
        ["Laikipia",483,0.931],
        ["Nakuru",3482,0.161],
        ["Narok",843,0.073],
        ["Kajiado",881,0.079],
        ["Kericho",2661,0.295],
        ["Bomet",1005,0.115]
    ]
    }
]
```

The code I have created is as follows (note I am using the Rand feature to just create some dummy data for the time being):

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno($conn)) {
        echo "Failed to connect to DataBase: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    else {

        /* Declare arrays */
        $output_array =array();
        $region_array = array();
        $county_array = array();

        $fetch_region = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT distinct region_code as id, region as x, sum(entrants) as value,
        FLOOR(RAND()*(60-10+1))+20 as market_share,
        FLOOR(RAND()*(70-50+1))+20 as total_share
        from reporting_summary_county
        group by region_code") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    while ($row_region = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch_region)) {
        $region_array['id'] = $row_region['id'];
        $region_array['x'] = $row_region['x'];
        $region_array['value'] = $row_region['value'];
        $region_array['market_share'] = $row_region['market_share'];
        $region_array['total_share'] = $row_region['total_share'];
        $region_array['revenue'] = array();

        $fetch_county = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT county, sum(entrants) as v1, round((sum(entrants)/sum(population))*100,3) as v2
        from reporting_summary_county
        where region_code = ".$row_region['id']."
        group by county"
        ) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

        while ($row_county = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch_county)) {
            $county_array['county']=$row_county['county'];
            $county_array['v1']=$row_county['v1'];
            $county_array['v2']=$row_county['v2'];
            array_push($region_array['revenue'],$county_array);
        }

        array_push($output_array,$region_array);
}

$jsonData = json_encode($output_array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);


echo $jsonData; 
}
```

On running the code, the following message is output:

```html
Unknown column 'KE.CE' in 'where clause'
```

I believe the problem stems from this line:

```
where region_code = ".$row_region['id']."
```

I have tried different options with the output and tried not to escape the variable, with no success.

It is interesting, that when i replace the $row_region variable, with a hard coded region it returns the expected output, however, the inner revenue data is repeated for the region hard coded.

The output also highlights another problem, in that the field name is also displayed in the revenue section output, and I only want to see the value. I need to look into this further.

```
where region_code = 'KE.CE'
```

Output from this change:

```json
[ { "id": "KE.CE", "x": "Central", "value": "5033", "market_share": "51", "total_share": "20", "revenue": [ { "county": "Kiambu", "v1": "2174", "v2": "0.090" }, { "county": "Kirinyaga", "v1": "395", "v2": "0.065" }, { "county": "Muranga", "v1": "487", "v2": "0.046" }, { "county": "Nyandarua", "v1": "1153", "v2": "0.181" }, { "county": "Nyeri", "v1": "824", "v2": "0.109" } ] }, { "id": "KE.CO", "x": "Coast", "value": "5692", "market_share": "26", "total_share": "24", "revenue": [ { "county": "Kiambu", "v1": "2174", "v2": "0.090" }, { "county": "Kirinyaga", "v1": "395", "v2": "0.065" }, { "county": "Muranga", "v1": "487", "v2": "0.046" }, { "county": "Nyandarua", "v1": "1153", "v2": "0.181" }, { "county": "Nyeri", "v1": "824", "v2": "0.109" } ] }, { "id": "KE.NA", "x": "Nairobi(Province)", "value": "10870", "market_share": "25", "total_share": "38", "revenue": [ { "county": "Kiambu", "v1": "2174", "v2": "0.090" }, { "county": "Kirinyaga", "v1": "395", "v2": "0.065" }, { "county": "Muranga", "v1": "487", "v2": "0.046" }, { "county": "Nyandarua", "v1": "1153", "v2": "0.181" }, { "county": "Nyeri", "v1": "824", "v2": "0.109" } ] }, { "id": "KE.NE", "x": "North Eastern", "value": "4726", "market_share": "59", "total_share": "23", "revenue": [ { "county": "Kiambu", "v1": "2174", "v2": "0.090" }, { "county": "Kirinyaga", "v1": "395", "v2": "0.065" }, { "county": "Muranga", "v1": "487", "v2": "0.046" }, { "county": "Nyandarua", "v1": "1153", "v2": "0.181" }, { "county": "Nyeri", "v1": "824", "v2": "0.109" } ] }, { "id": "KE.NR", "x": "Eastern", "value": "5467", "market_share": "45", "total_share": "20", "revenue": [ { "county": "Kiambu", "v1": "2174", "v2": "0.090" }, { "county": "Kirinyaga", "v1": "395", "v2": "0.065" }, { "county": "Muranga", "v1": "487", "v2": "0.046" }, { "county": "Nyandarua", "v1": "1153", "v2": "0.181" }, { "county": "Nyeri", "v1": "824", "v2": "0.109" } ] }, { "id": "KE.NY", "x": "Nyanza", "value": "12130", "market_share": "63", "total_share": "31", "revenue": [ { "county": "Kiambu", "v1": "2174", "v2": "0.090" }, { "county": "Kirinyaga", "v1": "395", "v2": "0.065" }, { "county": "Muranga", "v1": "487", "v2": "0.046" }, { "county": "Nyandarua", "v1": "1153", "v2": "0.181" }, { "county": "Nyeri", "v1": "824", "v2": "0.109" } ] }, { "id": "KE.RV", "x": "Rift Valley", "value": "15855", "market_share": "30", "total_share": "20", "revenue": [ { "county": "Kiambu", "v1": "2174", "v2": "0.090" }, { "county": "Kirinyaga", "v1": "395", "v2": "0.065" }, { "county": "Muranga", "v1": "487", "v2": "0.046" }, { "county": "Nyandarua", "v1": "1153", "v2": "0.181" }, { "county": "Nyeri", "v1": "824", "v2": "0.109" } ] }, { "id": "KE.WE", "x": "Western", "value": "5163", "market_share": "43", "total_share": "25", "revenue": [ { "county": "Kiambu", "v1": "2174", "v2": "0.090" }, { "county": "Kirinyaga", "v1": "395", "v2": "0.065" }, { "county": "Muranga", "v1": "487", "v2": "0.046" }, { "county": "Nyandarua", "v1": "1153", "v2": "0.181" }, { "county": "Nyeri", "v1": "824", "v2": "0.109" } ] } ]
```

Update:
If I change the code to use a concatenated string:

```
where region_code = '".$row_region['id']."'
```

The output returns a blank screen.

I have also modified the code to use bind variables, and this returns the same blank output.

```
$query = "SELECT county, sum(entrants) as v1, round((sum(entrants)/sum(population))*100,3) as v2
        from reporting_summary_county
        where region_code =?
        group by county";
        $sql = $conn->prepare($query);
        $sql->bind_param("s", $row_region['id']);
        if (!$sql->execute()) {
            echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $sql->error;
        }
        $fetch_county = $sql->get_result();
```

If i make an error in the bind_param section as an example and change it to something non existent:

```
$sql->bind_param("s", $test['id']);
```

This returns an output, minus the revenue section.

```json
[ { "id": "KE.CE", "x": "Central", "value": "5033", "market_share": "44", "total_share": "37", "revenue": [] }, { "id": "KE.CO", "x": "Coast", "value": "5692", "market_share": "65", "total_share": "30", "revenue": [] }, { "id": "KE.NA", "x": "Nairobi(Province)", "value": "10870", "market_share": "45", "total_share": "25", "revenue": [] }, { "id": "KE.NE", "x": "North Eastern", "value": "4726", "market_share": "59", "total_share": "27", "revenue": [] }, { "id": "KE.NR", "x": "Eastern", "value": "5467", "market_share": "50", "total_share": "37", "revenue": [] }, { "id": "KE.NY", "x": "Nyanza", "value": "12130", "market_share": "41", "total_share": "35", "revenue": [] }, { "id": "KE.RV", "x": "Rift Valley", "value": "15855", "market_share": "52", "total_share": "36", "revenue": [] }, { "id": "KE.WE", "x": "Western", "value": "5163", "market_share": "68", "total_share": "29", "revenue": [] } ]
```

This seems to infer to me, that there is an issue in the code for the $query section.
I have been looking at this too long and clearly can't see the wood for the trees.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: The problem of no data returning was down to the spelling of a county. I found this by using ```var_dump($county_array);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just think about the output of

```
where region_code = ".$row_region['id']."
```

... if you mentally concatenate the string will be:

```
where region_code = KE.CE
```

and as you can see, it's not valid... instead you should use

```
where region_code = '".$row_region['id']."'
```

be aware that injecting string in query IS VERY DANGEROUS and allows other to inject possibly malicious code in it (not always, but most of the times)... consider migrating to prepared statements

Comment: Thank you for the response Alberto. As i had mentioned in the query, I had tried different options. When i try as you suggest, which i thought would be correct as you point out, the response is a blank screen, with no output.

Comment: I have updated the question based on your feedback Alberto.

Comment: @MikeM hi, sorry for the delay... i see that you have marked the answer as correct... should i consider your question as resolved?